# Continuous slideshow with Unslider

Tags: jquery, loops, slider

I'm using [**Unslider**](http://unslider.com/) at the moment and I'm wondering if there is any way to make the slideshow continue to the right when switching from the last slide to the first one. At the moment it goes through all the slides from right to left when jumping to the first one from the last.

If that isn't possible, is it possible to make it go backwards from the last one instead? Like this:

**1 - 2 - 3 - 4   //  4 - 3 - 2 - 1 // 1 - 2 - 3**...

Really appreciate answers! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, unslider doesn't support either of those two. If you don't mind getting a little dirty, you can modify the .to method in the code to do the 1-2-3-4-3-2-1-2-3-4-etc... that you mentioned.

If you decide to go that route, and need help, let me know. I would probably modify the script to keep track of whether we're moving forward or backward, and then use index and li.length to determine which way to send the slider.

Also, if you want the carousel feel where it just keeps scrolling left to right and the content just keeps repeating, jCarousel supports that: https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel.

Answer (score 0):

New to javascript but this is what i did:

// another variable on current unslider instance  this.order which takes two values: r(reverse) & f (forward)

//  If it's out of bounds, go to the first slide
            if(!this.items.eq(index).length) this.order = 'r';

```
                    if (this.order === 'r')index = index -2;

        if(index < 0) {this.order = 'f';index=0;}
```